# options_for_select doesn't choose a category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'd like to select category in form_for

```
f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.select(:title, :id).map{|cat|[cat.title, cat.id]})
```

but everytime when I check category_id in object, is equal nil.
Could someone help me, where I make a mistake?

Solve!
I forgot about category_id in params.required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.pluck` instead of `.select` which would give you an array of tuples straight away:

```
[[1, "A title"], [2, "Another title"]]

f.select(:category_id, Category.pluck(:id, :title))
```

Rails also [has convenient helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models) for dealing with collections:

```
f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :title)
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, still I get category_id=nil.. Maybe not select is a problem..?